# Android App stopped when button is clicked

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I am completely brand new to Android developement and this is the first day I ever touched Android studio. I'm implementing a note taking app which has the settings page that help users to change the colour of the text. The settings page has 3 radio buttons (3 colours) contained in radio group and a save button to save the settings. When the save button is clicked it will change the colour of the text in another layout/xml file called NoteEditor. when I tried to run the app, I clicked the save . I already register Settings class to AndroidManifest Please Help!!

Below are my code

Settings.Java

```
    package com.example.sunny.mynote;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * Created by Sunny on 19/04/2015.
 */
public class Settings extends Activity {

    private RadioGroup RadioGroup1;
    private RadioButton rdbRed, rdbBlue, rdbOrange;
    private Button btnSave;
    private EditText textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.settings, null);

        RadioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);

        RadioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if(checkedId == R.id.rdbRed)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Red",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    RadioGroup1.check(R.id.rdbRed);
                }
                else if(checkedId == R.id.rdbBlue)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Blue",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    RadioGroup1.check(R.id.rdbBlue);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Orange",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    RadioGroup1.check(R.id.rdbOrange);
                }
            }
        });

        rdbRed = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbRed);
        rdbBlue = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbBlue);
        rdbOrange = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbOrange);
        textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
        btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Save);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int selectedId = RadioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    if(selectedId == rdbRed.getId()) {
                        String color1 = String.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                        String color2 = String.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                        String color3 = String.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditorActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("textValue", color1);
                        intent.putExtra("textValue1", color2);
                        intent.putExtra("textValue2", color3);
                        startActivity(intent);
                } else if(selectedId == rdbBlue.getId()) {
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0066FF"));
                } else {
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6600"));
                }
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}
```

NoteEditorActivity.Java

```
package com.example.sunny.mynote;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.sunny.mynote.com.example.sunny.mynote.data.NoteItem;

/**
 * Created by Sunny on 19/04/2015.
 */
public class NoteEditorActivity extends Activity {

    private NoteItem note;
    private String textValue1;
    private String textValue2;
    private String textValue3;

    EditText textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        note = new NoteItem();
        note.setKey(intent.getStringExtra("key"));
        note.setText(intent.getStringExtra("text"));

        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
        et.setText(note.getText());
        et.setSelection(note.getText().length());

        //Intent intent = getIntent();
        textValue1 = intent.getStringExtra("textValue");
        textValue2 = intent.getStringExtra("textValue1");
        textValue3 = intent.getStringExtra("textValue2");

        if(textValue1 != null){
            textView.setText(textValue1);
        }
        else if (textValue2 != null){
            textView.setText(textValue2);
        }
        else {
            textView.setText(textValue3);
        }
    }

    private void saveAndFinish()
    {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
        String noteText = et.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("key", note.getKey());
        intent.putExtra("text", noteText);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
        {
            saveAndFinish();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        saveAndFinish();
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
04-22 20:45:11.283  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-22 20:45:11.303  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:11.353  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:11.353  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:11.383  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:11.393  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:12.433  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:12.433  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onDetachedFromWindow
04-22 20:45:12.433  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:12.443  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-22 20:45:12.453  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
04-22 20:45:12.783  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-22 20:45:12.783  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:17.233  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-22 20:45:17.233  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417e0da0)
04-22 20:45:17.243  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sunny.mynote, PID: 30609
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.sunny.mynote.Settings.saveButtonPressed(Settings.java:36)
            at com.example.sunny.mynote.Settings.access$100(Settings.java:19)
            at com.example.sunny.mynote.Settings$2.onClick(Settings.java:84)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4630)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19339)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 20:45:18.573  30609-30609/com.example.sunny.mynote I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 30609 SIG: 9
04-22 20:45:18.633  31515-31515/com.example.sunny.mynote I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
04-22 20:45:18.653  31515-31515/com.example.sunny.mynote I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-N9005_4.4.2_0040
04-22 20:45:18.653  31515-31515/com.example.sunny.mynote I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
04-22 20:45:18.653  31515-31515/com.example.sunny.mynote E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
04-22 20:45:18.653  31515-31515/com.example.sunny.mynote E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> com.example.sunny.mynote [ userId:0 | appId:10383 ]
04-22 20:45:18.653  31515-31515/com.example.sunny.mynote D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-22 20:45:18.673  31515-31515/com.example.sunny.mynote I/dalvikvm﹕ Enabling JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 7...
04-22 20:45:18.743  31515-31515/com.example.sunny.mynote W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-22 20:45:18.743  31515-31515/com.example.sunny.mynote I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
04-22 20:45:18.783  31515-31515/com.example.sunny.mynote E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
04-22 20:45:18.813  31515-31515/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-22 20:45:18.813  31515-31515/com.example.sunny.mynote W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417e0da0)
04-22 20:45:18.813  31515-31515/com.example.sunny.mynote E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sunny.mynote, PID: 31515
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sunny.mynote/com.example.sunny.mynote.NoteEditorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.sunny.mynote.NoteEditorActivity.onCreate(NoteEditorActivity.java:53)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 20:45:21.793  31515-31515/com.example.sunny.mynote I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 31515 SIG: 9
04-22 20:45:22.033  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-22 20:45:22.043  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
04-22 20:45:22.093  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
04-22 20:45:22.103  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-22 20:45:22.123  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-22 20:45:22.123  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:22.143  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-22 20:45:22.143  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:22.153  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:22.173  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:22.173  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:22.203  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:23.623  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-22 20:45:23.643  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:23.713  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:23.713  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:23.733  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:23.763  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:24.723  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:24.723  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onDetachedFromWindow
04-22 20:45:24.723  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:24.723  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-22 20:45:24.743  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
04-22 20:45:25.073  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-22 20:45:25.073  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:26.593  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-22 20:45:26.593  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417e0da0)
04-22 20:45:26.593  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sunny.mynote, PID: 31846
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.sunny.mynote.Settings.saveButtonPressed(Settings.java:36)
            at com.example.sunny.mynote.Settings.access$100(Settings.java:19)
            at com.example.sunny.mynote.Settings$2.onClick(Settings.java:84)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4630)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19339)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 20:45:31.993  31846-31846/com.example.sunny.mynote I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 31846 SIG: 9
04-22 20:45:32.193  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-22 20:45:32.193  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
04-22 20:45:32.223  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
04-22 20:45:32.243  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-22 20:45:32.253  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-22 20:45:32.253  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:32.263  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-22 20:45:32.263  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:32.273  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:32.293  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:32.313  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:32.323  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:33.533  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-22 20:45:33.553  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:33.603  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:33.603  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:33.643  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:33.643  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:34.423  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:34.423  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onDetachedFromWindow
04-22 20:45:34.423  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:34.433  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-22 20:45:34.443  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
04-22 20:45:34.753  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-22 20:45:34.753  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-22 20:45:38.373  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-22 20:45:38.373  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417e0da0)
04-22 20:45:38.373  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sunny.mynote, PID: 32455
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.sunny.mynote.Settings.saveButtonPressed(Settings.java:36)
            at com.example.sunny.mynote.Settings.access$100(Settings.java:19)
            at com.example.sunny.mynote.Settings$2.onClick(Settings.java:84)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4630)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19339)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 20:45:39.763  32455-32455/com.example.sunny.mynote I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 32455 SIG: 9
04-22 20:45:39.953  32526-32526/com.example.sunny.mynote W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-22 20:45:39.953  32526-32526/com.example.sunny.mynote I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
04-22 20:45:39.973  32526-32526/com.example.sunny.mynote E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
04-22 20:45:40.003  32526-32526/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-22 20:45:40.003  32526-32526/com.example.sunny.mynote W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417e0da0)
04-22 20:45:40.003  32526-32526/com.example.sunny.mynote E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sunny.mynote, PID: 32526
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sunny.mynote/com.example.sunny.mynote.NoteEditorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.sunny.mynote.NoteEditorActivity.onCreate(NoteEditorActivity.java:53)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5389)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2350)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:163)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1257)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you just enter error log and not the all logcat so it is easy to understand where is wrong.

Comment: please post complete [logcat](https://politecuriosity.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/logcat.jpg).

Comment: is there any textview in setting.xml ?? Please post settings.xml

Comment: Are all the error log are the red lines in logcat?

Comment: @LuluHarper , yes post all the data requested in comments

Comment: settings.xml update. No there is no text view in settings.xml I', trying to use the save button in settings.xml to change the EditText in note_editor_acivity.xml

Comment: Did you use any emulator like genymotion or else for testing.

Comment: I use my phonne, Galaxy Note 3

Comment: line 74 in settings.java is textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6600"));

Comment: Is there a Save Button defined in the xml? What is its id? Looks like `btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Save);` is returning `null``. And a null pointer exception is thrown when you call onClickListener on a null object. Post your xml file to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are getting null pointer there because you are in Settings class and you are initialising text view but text view is in NoteEditor class. Initialise text view in NoteEditor class.

The following line must be in NoteEditor class:

```
 EditText textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
```

You are just creating an object of intent and not creating an object of intent you need to send a the text value to NoteEditor class and then set the text as shown below:

Do the following in your onClick method remove the following line:

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
```

Change the above lines as shown below:

```
String color1 = String.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
String color2 = String.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
String color3 = String.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditorActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("textValue", color1);
intent.putExtra("textValue1", color2);
intent.putExtra("textValue2", color3);
startActivity(intent);
```

After this in Note Editor class do the following:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    textValue1 = intent.getStringExtra("textValue");
textValue2 = intent.getStringExtra("textValue1");
textValue3 = intent.getStringExtra("textValue2");

if(textValue1 != null){
    textView.setText(textValue1);
}
else if (textValue2 != null){
    textView.setText(textValue2);
}
else {
textView.setText(textValue3);
}
```

Change your Settings.java to the code shown below, copy the following code from the line I have put here and paste it, do not remove complete code in your class be careful while copying:

```
    public class Settings extends Activity {

        private RadioGroup RadioGroup1;
        private RadioButton rdbRed, rdbBlue, rdbOrange;
        private Button btnSave;
    private String color1, color2, color3;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
            setContentView(R.layout.settings);

            RadioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);

            RadioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    if(checkedId == R.id.rdbRed)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Red",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        RadioGroup1.check(R.id.rdbRed);
                    }
                    else if(checkedId == R.id.rdbBlue)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Blue",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        RadioGroup1.check(R.id.rdbBlue);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Orange",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        RadioGroup1.check(R.id.rdbOrange);
                    }
                }
            });

            rdbRed = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbRed);
            rdbBlue = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbBlue);
            rdbOrange = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbOrange);
                  btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Save);
            btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int selectedId = RadioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                        if(selectedId == rdbRed.getId()) {
                            color1 = String.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

                                          } 
else if(selectedId == rdbBlue.getId()) {
            color2 = String.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#0066FF"));
                    } 
else {
              color3 = String.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF6600"));
                    }
                }

            });

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditorActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("textValue", color1);
                            intent.putExtra("textValue1", color2);
                            intent.putExtra("textValue2", color3);
                            startActivity(intent);


        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
```

do not remove any code which is already present above public class line.

Similarly copy the below code and paste it in NoteEditor class:

```
public class NoteEditorActivity extends Activity {

    private NoteItem note;
    private String textValue1;
    private String textValue2;
    private String textValue3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

EditText textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);


        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        note = new NoteItem();
        note.setKey(intent.getStringExtra("key"));
        note.setText(intent.getStringExtra("text"));

        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
        et.setText(note.getText());
        et.setSelection(note.getText().length());

        //Intent intent = getIntent();
        textValue1 = intent.getStringExtra("textValue");
        textValue2 = intent.getStringExtra("textValue1");
        textValue3 = intent.getStringExtra("textValue2");

        if(textValue1 != null){
            textView.setText(textValue1);
        }
        else if (textValue2 != null){
            textView.setText(textValue2);
        }
        else {
            textView.setText(textValue3);
        }
    }

    private void saveAndFinish()
    {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
        String noteText = et.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("key", note.getKey());
        intent.putExtra("text", noteText);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
        {
            saveAndFinish();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        saveAndFinish();
    }
}
```

Let me know after doing this are you still getting errors.
This will serve your purpose. Hope it helps.

Comment: check the edited answer, carefully edit your code only copy the newly made changes.

Comment: After doing these changes you should not get any errors please let me know.

Comment: I have made some new changes after previous edit make sure you make those changes.

Comment: I got no error now, but when I try to go to settings page the whole app will crash

Comment: That is a different issue, Please create another question for that. So every one will answer. If my answer helped you then please accept the answer and up vote it. Please paste the link to the new question I will answer if I know the solution.

Comment: I also have another question here, please help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796008/android-action-bar-button-does-not-show-up/29796219?noredirect=1#comment47722000_29796219

Comment: try the last answer in that question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your layout is not inflated, I suggest you to add notetext EditText in setting.xml layout. So you can directly inflate that layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/noteText"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change Text Colour"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_weight="0.04"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.04"
    android:id="@+id/RadioGroup1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Red"
        android:id="@+id/rdbRed" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Blue"
        android:id="@+id/rdbBlue" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Orange"
        android:id="@+id/rdbOrange" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:layout_width="98dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Save"
    android:id="@+id/btn_Save"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="0.04" />
```

You need to adjust this layout according to your need. I dont know how structure do you want to display. But Firstly make change and then do adjustments.and remove this line

```
  LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.settings, null);
```

Comment: but the EditText is actually in NoteEditor, i cant move it to settings

Comment: Is it another activity if not then how you will show that noteEditor in current activity.