# Android Action Bar Button does not show up

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

I'm implementing an action bar for my app which has 2 menu buttons : Add and Settings. In Designer view the 2 buttons still apprear like normal. However when I run the app 2 buttons does not show up at all. Please help

Below are my code:

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.sunny.mynote;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.sunny.mynote.com.example.sunny.mynote.data.NoteDataSource;
import com.example.sunny.mynote.com.example.sunny.mynote.data.NoteItem;

import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public static final int EDITOR_ACRIVITY_REQUEST = 1001;
    public static final int SETTINGS_REQUEST = 1003;
    private static final int MENU_DELETE_ID = 1002;
    private int currentNoteId;
    private NoteDataSource datasource;
    List<NoteItem> notesList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

        datasource = new NoteDataSource(this);

        refreshDisplay();
    }

    private void refreshDisplay() {
        notesList = datasource.findAll();
        ArrayAdapter<NoteItem> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<NoteItem>(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, notesList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    //Add the Actions to the Action Bar
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    //Respond to Action Buttons
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_create:
                createNote();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                Settings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void createNote()
    {
        NoteItem note = NoteItem.getNew();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditorActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", note.getKey());
        intent.putExtra("text", note.getText());
        startActivityForResult(intent, EDITOR_ACRIVITY_REQUEST);
    }

    private void Settings()
    {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent2, SETTINGS_REQUEST);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        NoteItem note = notesList.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditorActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", note.getKey());
        intent.putExtra("text", note.getText());
        startActivityForResult(intent, EDITOR_ACRIVITY_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == EDITOR_ACRIVITY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
            NoteItem note = new NoteItem();
            note.setKey(data.getStringExtra("key"));
            note.setText(data.getStringExtra("text"));
            datasource.update(note);
            refreshDisplay();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        currentNoteId = (int)info.id;
        menu.add(0, MENU_DELETE_ID, 0, "Delete");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == MENU_DELETE_ID)
        {
            NoteItem note = notesList.get(currentNoteId);
            datasource.remove(note);
            refreshDisplay();
        }

        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

menu.xml

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_create" android:title="@string/action_create"
        android:icon="@drawable/create_note"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="ifRoom" android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use in Your Java File after setContentView

```
getSupportActionBar().show();
```

Comment: he/she is not using any support library

Comment: appCompat is always there. And no other library is required.

Comment: and he/she is not using that.

Comment: Then use This before setContentView   requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

Comment: And FYI he/she is using appcompat. see code properly

Comment: i had an error. When i tried to to getSupportActionBar there is nothing like that appear. Please help

Comment: then use the next option I told you      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

Comment: it still does not show up, please check my menu.xml

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </style>

Comment: Can you show me one screen shot of that. As everything is fine.

Comment: I cant send you the picture cuz i dont have enough reputation. Is there any better way I can show use my code. Do you have teamviewer or any tool to chat?

Comment: Replace your onCreate with this Once and Check and extend ActionBarActivity..............................................protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  getSupportActionBar().show();
  
//  registerForContextMenu(getListView());
//
//        datasource = new NoteDataSource(this);
//
//        refreshDisplay();

 }

Answer (score 1):

add in menu.xml `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".Main">

    <item android:id="@+id/paste" android:title="Paste"
        android:orderInCategory="100" 
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

**and in main:**

```
//Add the Actions to the Action Bar
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
//Respond to Action Buttons
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
            openSearch();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            openSettings();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**see this:** https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Comment: can you post here your menu.xml

Comment: try with "ifRoom | withText"

Comment: try to set onCreateOptionsMenu like me and check are you call good menu.xml (if you have more than one).

Comment: yes I did the same thing but it still does not show up

Answer (score 1):

I would like to see you menu xml file for this Activity.
Please try this one, change icon and id. 
Notice that there is *android:showAsAction="always"* NOT *app:showAsAction="always"*:

```
<item android:id="@+id/Add_New_Note"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
    android:title="Add new note"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

I had the same problem, hope it will help.

Comment: i tried to change mine to android:showAsAction="always" but show error "should use with appcombat collection library"

Answer (score 1):

Include this code in your MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

Inside your onCreate()

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Give Add and Settings Item in res -> Menu folder.

It will display ActionBar.

Give your extends ListViewActivity in findViewById